# How to make an unique id in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I want to implement a unique id like this- AS-R9999-1 / AS-R9999-A . And it can goes upto 1-5 or A-F . However in future my customer will be increased but id can not be long , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Cake works with UUID or integer id primary keys only.

You can still have your custom fields, just not as a primary key. you could implement this in `beforeSave()` of the model with something like

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (empty($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey]) { // this is a create as id is empty
        $this->data[$this->alias]['your_field'] = $this->_generateYourCustomValue();
    }
    return true;
}
```